# definition of the vector area of a loop

Tags: vector-analysis

I came across this question:

Air is flowing with a speed $0.4 \  \text{m/s}$
in the direction of the vector $(−1, −1, 1)$. Calculate the volume of air
flowing per second through the loop which consists of straight lines joining, in turn, the following points:
$(1,1,0), (1,0,0), (0,0,0), (0,1,1), (1,1,1)$ and $(1,1,0)$.

the loop obviously doesn't lie in a plane, so how do we calculate the flux? and is there a proper way of defining the vector area of such loop?

Comment: and there are plenty of ways to fill the loop with planes, how do we know which one to choose?

Comment: There are uncountably many ways to fill the loop with a surface (need not be piecewise-planar). But you have a direction in which the air is moving. The volume of air that passes through the loop is not proportional to the area, but to the integral of the inner product of the vector area differential element (whose direction is normal to the surface at each point) with that wind direction. This integral will be the same over all surfaces filling the loop.